# Scheme - Number of internal nodes of a binary search tree which have exactly one child

Tags: tree, scheme

Just as the title says I want to find the number of nodes which have one child and can't figure out what's wrong with my code:

Here's how I define the trees

```
(define (make-tree v left-tree right-tree)
  (list v left-tree right-tree))

(define (value T) (car T))

(define (left T) (cadr T))

(define (right T) (caddr T))
```

Code for finding the number of nodes:

```
(define (count-one-child T)
  (let* ((sum 0))
    (cond ((null? T) 0)
          ((and (null? (left T))(null? (right T))) sum)
          ((and (null? (left T)) (not (null? (right T))))
           (begin (set! sum (+ 1 sum)) (count-one-child (right T)) sum))
          ((and (null? (right T))(not (null? (left T))))
           (begin (set! sum (+ 1 sum)) (count-one-child (left T)) sum))
          (else (begin (count-one-child (left T)) (count-one-child (right T)))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using `set!` when writing procedures in Scheme, that's the imperative way to think about a solution in other programming languages, but not the right approach in Scheme.

To solve this problem, you just have to be thorough and consider all the cases, and add `1` only when the conditions are right. And don't forget to advance the recursion, and combine the results of each subtree. Try this:

```
(define (count-one-child T)
        ; empty tree
  (cond ((null? T) 0)
        ; a leaf
        ((and (null? (left  T)) (null? (right T))) 0)
        ; only right subtree exists, add 1
        ((null? (left  T))
         (+ 1 (count-one-child (right T))))
        ; only left subtree exists, add 1
        ((null? (right T))
         (+ 1 (count-one-child (left  T))))
        ; both subtrees exist
        (else
         (+ (count-one-child (left  T))
            (count-one-child (right T))))))
```

Comment: @ThisPlayName when you absolutely _have to_ mutate state and/or save state between calls to a procedure, but most of the time you want to program in a functional, stateless style that relies heavily on recursion (passing modified values as parameters) and using built-ins, higher-order functions and function composition.

Answer (score 0):

As Óscar mentions in his answer using mutation is not the preferred way, however I see that you have asked how one would do it with mutations and this is how:

```
(define (count-one-child T)
  (define sum 0)
  (define (aux T)
    (let* ((l (left T))
           (r (right T))
           (nulll? (null? l))
           (nullr? (null? r)))      
      (if nulll?
          (cond ((not nullr?)
                 (set! sum (+ 1 sum))
                 (aux r)))
          (cond (nullr?
                 (set! sum (+ 1 sum))
                 (aux l))
                (else
                 (aux l)
                 (aux r))))))
  (when (not (null? T))     
    (aux T))

  sum)
```

As you see `sum` is outside the recursive procedure `aux` or else the `sum` variable would be a different one for each recursion. In the code above the helper has access to mutate `sum` which is created before the helper is applied.

It doesn't take much rewriting in order to have it functional. Instead of mutating a variable you can have it as argument and you update it the same time as the recursion:

```
(define (count-one-child T)
  (define (aux T sum)
    (let* ((l (left T))
           (r (right T))
           (nulll? (null? l))
           (nullr? (null? r)))
      (if nulll?
          (if nullr?
              sum
              (aux r (+ 1 sum)))
          (if nullr?
              (aux l (+ 1 sum))
              (aux l (aux r sum))))))
  (if (null? T)
      0
      (aux T 0)))
```

This does just as well as the mutative version, perhaps even slightly better.